# AngularJS : Understanding service when using $http.post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I am moving all http calls in my controllers to services, using `$q` to promise... Everything seems to work till I refresh the page then the content disappears.

**Setting:** In my login service, I have a function which does an `$http.post`, it takes `username` and `password`. Then the response data is put in the promise.

**Problem:** Though the service works, It is trying resend the http call when the page is refreshed. The call then fails because the are no login details.

**Question:** How do I keep/store the original data so when the page is refreshed (*and user is still signed in*) and when I use the service in other controllers it does not do the http call it just returns the data?

**Service:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.factory('loginService', function($http, $q) {
    var deferResults = $q.defer();
     return {
    appContent: function(login_username, login_password) {
        $http.post('/login',{username: login_username, password: login_password}).success(function(data) {
          deferResults.resolve(myData);
      });
      return deferResults.promise;
    }
});
```

**Controllers:**

```
    function loginPageCtrl($scope, loginService) {
       $scope.login = function (login_username, login_password, login_rememberMe) {
          loginService.appContent(login_username, login_username).then(function (data) {
             $scope.pageOneContent = data;
          });
       };
    };

    function pageTwoCtrl($scope, loginService) {
      // Use the same data when page is refreshed
      // without having to pass-in login details

      loginService.appContent().then(function (data) {
         $scope.pageTwoContent = data;
      });
   };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course that happens, your app loses all its state when the page is refreshed. You need to persist that username and password somewhere, like a cookie, and then retrieve that then make your second `$http` call, even better just keep a token in a cookie and use that for authentication. Use angular's `$cookieStore` to persist the login details:

```
var userData={username:login_username,password:login_password};
$cookieStore.put('user_data', userData);
```

and then when the controller loads, check if the cookie exists:

```
var userData = $cookieStore.get('user_data');
return userData
```

Check the source in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662778/example-of-an-spa-with-a-login-screen-that-uses-angularjs-and-connects-to-asp-ne/21842533#21842533) to see this in action.

To recap, every time the controller loads check the cookie, if its undefined then redirect the user to a login page, if it's not then extract the toke/username/password and make your `$http` call.

Comment: Is the no way of archiving the same without using a cookie? I am trying to avoid putting raw passwords in a cookie

Comment: Check the link I provided, in that answer there is pretty good implementation of authentication. Yes, and you should never store passwords client side, you store a token returned by the server in the cookie.