# best solution for single page authentication in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router

I have tried many solutions in the internet but did not went successful.

```
            var myDataPromise = loginService.getData();
            myDataPromise.then(function(data) {  // this is only run after $http completes

                if(!isLogin) {
                    if(!data.logout) {

                    } else {
                        $location.url("pages/signin");
                    }
                } else {
                    if(data.logout) {
                        $location.url("pages/signin");
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });
```

`loginService` returns the user status whether he is authorized or not and this service use $http ajax get request to get the data.
What I want is to check the user status for every route and redirect to signin page if he is not logged without showing the requested page.
In my case there is a issue. If I click browser back button after I logged out it shows the previous page for a while and then redirect to signin page plus if user request a page after the session expire browser shows the requested page for a while and then direct to signin page. What is the best solution for this isse ? thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662778/example-of-an-spa-with-a-login-screen-that-uses-angularjs-and-connects-to-asp-ne)

Comment: I just wrote a detailed blog article and example application about this very topic http://jonsamwell.com/url-route-authorization-and-security-in-angular/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check every state you can add an event listener to `$stateChangeStart`

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    event.preventDefault();
    loginService.getData().then(
        function() {
            $state.go(toState, toParams);
        },
        function() {
            $state.go('login');
        });
})
```